# Codeigniter delete multiple rows with checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I'm trying to delete multiple private messages from my database by selecting multiple checkboxes in the inbox and clicking submit to delete. I have the code below but nothing happens. I'm not sure what I'm missing..

View:

```
<?php echo form_open('pm/remove_checked'); ?>

<?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>   
    <input type="checkbox" name="msg[]" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" />
    <?php echo $row->from; ?>
    <?php echo $row->subject; ?>    
    <?php echo date("m/d/Y",strtotime($row->msg_date)); ?>          
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php echo form_submit('delete', 'Delete'); ?>

</form>
```

Controller:

```
function remove_checked()
{
        //validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('msg[]', 'Private Message', 'required|xss_clean'); 

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
        {
            $data['query'] = $this->Pm_model->received_msg(); 
            $this->load->view('pm/inbox', $data);   
        }
        else //success
        {
            $checked_messages = $this->input->post('msg'); //selected messages
            $this->Pm_model->delete_checked($checked_messages);

            //redirect to inbox                                     
        }

}
```

Model:

```
function delete_checked($checked_messages) 
{
    $checked_messages = array();
    foreach ($checked_messages as $msg_id):

          $this->db->select('id');
          $this->db->from('user_msg');
          $this->db->where('id', $msg_id);
          $this->db->limit(1);
          $query = $this->db->get();

          if ($query->num_rows() > 0) //if message exists
          {             
            $this->db->where('id', $msg_id);
            $this->db->where('recipient', $this->users->get_user_id()); //verify if recipient id is equal to logged in user id
            $this->db->delete('user_msg');

          }
          else 
          {
                return FALSE;
          } 

    endforeach;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your current `delete_checked()` method, you are `return`ing `FALSE` as soon as the first message is "found" that doesn't exist, this will prevent the rest of the messages from being deleted as `return` will stop execution of the loop. If you want to do it this way, use `continue` instead and consider using [transactions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html).

If you don't particularly care about generating individual errors for each message, your model function can be simplified a bit:

```
function delete_checked($message_ids) 
{
    $this->db
        ->where_in('id', $message_ids)
        ->where('recipient', $this->users->get_user_id())
        ->delete('user_msg');
    return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;
}
```

This will just attempt to delete the records. If they don't exist they will be ignored, and `$this->db->affected_rows()` *should* return the number of messages deleted. You can compare it to `count($message_ids)` if you want to ensure that *all* messages selected were deleted, or use this example method that only checks if at least one message was deleted. If the message doesn't exist, you don't need to delete it anyways.

[All the stuff Chris Schmitz mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178605/codeigniter-delete-multiple-rows-with-checkboxes/7178777#7178777) is correct and important as well, you have some very basic errors. You may want to *cast* to array instead of *assigning* `$checked_messages` to an empty array if you expect you may be passing a single id (integer or string) to this function. Like this:

```
$message_ids = (array) $message_ids;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I did not know about `continue` and transactions. For the loop I had to use `($checked_messages as $key => $msg_id)`.. I wasn't getting the value of the array item.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `$checked_msg` to the inputs that are checked, but then you are passing a different variable called `$checked_messages` to the model. You'll want to pass the `$checked_msg` var to the model.

Also, in your model, you are redeclaring the `$checked_messages` var and setting it to an empty array.  You'll need to remove that otherwise it will overwrite the info you are passing to the method.

Comment: Sorry, I made that mistake making the code readable. In my original script they are the same.